# how to open android builtin volume ui

Tags: android

I want my app to open the android built-in user interface for volume up.

```
Button bt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          KeyEvent ke=new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP);
          onKeyDown(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP,KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN);      
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank God,
By the grace of God i found it wow wowowowowo.

```
    Button bt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            AudioManager a=(AudioManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            a.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING,AudioManager.ADJUST_SAME,AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI|AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
        }
    });
```

[image]